# GoodData SSO URL to use in iFrame when using White Labeling

Tags: gooddata

Should the iFrame src still be "https://secure.gooddata.com/gdc/account/customerlogin?blahblahblah" when using a white labeled account. Or should you use your custom domain? e.g. "https://analytics.yourcompany.com/gdc/account/customerlogin?blahblahblah"

Answer (score 0):

Talked to support, and they said "If the portal is Whitelabeled all communication should be aligned with it." so I interpret that as a yes.